# Picking checkbox from database in table and update it back using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I picked data from database and arranged in table it also contains a checkbox as true if 1 and false if 0. The program should update the database according the checkbox functioning.

```
        <?php
            $query1="SELECT * FROM notices;";
            $result1=mysql_query($query1,$conn);
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            $pick=array();
            if($num_rows>0)
            {
                while ( ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) != null)
                { 
                $pick=$row['sl'];
                ?>
                <tr class="trc">
                    <td align="left"><label class="lab1"><?php echo($row['notice']); ?></label></td>
                    <td align="center"><label class="lab1"><?php echo($row['date']); ?></label></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="notice_id[]" value="YES" <?php 
                                            if($row['active']==1)
                                            {
                                                echo("checked");
                                            }
                                            ?> /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Below is the code to update data back to the dabase.

```
if(isset($_POST['up_note'])==true)
{
    $n_ids = $_POST['notice_id'];
    $sl_no = 1;

    foreach($n_ids as $key => $id)
    {
        echo($n_ids." | ".$id." | ".$key."<br />");

        $cb = ($POST['notice_id[$id]'] == 'YES')?'1':'0';

        if($cb==1)
        {
            $query3 = "UPDATE notices SET active = 1 WHERE sl='$sl_no';";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $conn);
            echo("entered");
        }
        else
        {
            $query3 = "UPDATE notices SET active = 0 WHERE sl='$sl_no';";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $conn);
            echo("not entered");
        }
        $sl_no = $sl_no + 1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: The code is not working. It is not saving updated data back into database.

Comment: Are you getting any entered or not entered and try to echo the mysql errors.

Comment: In above part where I fetched the data is okey. It is fetching all three records. But below where I tried to save the updated data into the database it is just showing "not entered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
            $query1="SELECT * FROM notices;";
            $result1=mysql_query($query1,$conn);
            $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            $pick=array();
            if($num_rows>0)
            {
                while ( ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) != null)
                { 
                $pick=$row['sl'];
?>
                <tr class="trc">
                    <td align="left"><label class="lab1"><?php echo($row['notice']); ?></label></td>
                    <td align="center"><label class="lab1"><?php echo($row['date']); ?></label></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="notice_id[]" value="<?php echo $pick; ?>" <?php if($row['active']==1){ echo("checked"); } ?> /></td>
                </tr>
<?php 
                }
            }
?>


/////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['up_note'])==true)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['notice_id'])){
        $n_ids = $_POST['notice_id'];
            $query_all = "UPDATE notices SET active = 0";
            $result_all = mysql_query($query_all, $conn);
        foreach($n_ids as $key => $id){
            $sl_no = $n_ids[$key];
            $query3 = "UPDATE notices SET active = 1 WHERE sl=$sl_no;";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $conn);
            echo("entered");    
        }
    } else {
           $query_all = "UPDATE notices SET active = 0";
           $result_all = mysql_query($query_all, $conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: $query3 = "UPDATE notices SET active = 1 WHERE sl='$id';";

Comment: I am using the above query. Your loop is working fine. Now problem is I don't know what to put in front of WHERE sl=????????

Comment: check the edited code the value of checkbox is the sl_no which you recieve on submit, and update the corresponding record

Comment: OH BOY! Its working, it is saving checkboxes where it is not checked, please solve the else condition also, if it is unchecked it should replace active=0.

Comment: Thank you for your time!
I made a little change in the above code of YOURS (of course it is yours) 

$query_all = "UPDATE notices SET active = 0";
$result_all = mysql_query($query_all, $conn);

I have put the above two commands above the isset($_POST['up_note'] below it is giving problem. Thank you once again!!!

Comment: If it is working then fine, place of it is according your need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this line

```
$cb = ($POST['notice_id[$id]'] == 'YES')?'1':'0';
```

I think it intended to be

```
$cb = ($_POST['notice_id[$id]'] == 'YES')?'1':'0';
```

And also replace the single quote with double quote as

```
$cb = ($_POST["notice_id[$id]"] == 'YES')?'1':'0';
```

Comment: It was mistake (may be one of them) but still not working. It is still going to not entered clause.

Comment: If you give the php variable within single quote that would be taken as string may be that's the reason here change the code as i changed above.

Comment: Thankx for your time, but it didn't solved the issue.